# Что за символ @?

Tags: cmake

В CMake в файлах типа Conifg.cmake.in используется символ `@` для обращения к переменным, например `@CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS@`.   Что это значит и чем отличается от `${CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS}`?

Пример можно [здесь](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file) посмотреть

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html